# Getting error while trying to install Karma

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am getting error when trying to install karma on my mac using $ npm install karma --save-dev

```
events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/os/Documents/Karma:Jasmine/package.json'
npm WARN Karma:Jasmine No description
npm WARN Karma:Jasmine No repository field.
npm WARN Karma:Jasmine No README data
npm WARN Karma:Jasmine No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have any `package.json` inside your current working directory. Try typing `npm init` and then `npm install karama --dev`.